How do I delete an image which was uploaded using the image uploader, but isn't included in any post?
If you copy an image and paste it into the Stack Exchange editor while creating or editing a Question or Answer, the image will be automatically uploaded to SE's image hosting service.
Is there a way to delete this image data from Stack Exchange? I have copies of the URLs, and by pasting those URLs into a browser I can see that the images still exist.
Note: I do not think the linked duplicate applies anymore since the image hosting arrangement with Imgur ended. Or, at least, an updated response should be posted that takes this change into account.

Its not a sister site of imgur, its basically a drop in replacement they run themselves

The accepted answer to the duplicate target still seems to apply here - you can flag for moderator attention or contact SE to have images removed. If you actually try this and it doesn't work, then edit the question to indicate so, and we'll reopen it. For now, I'm moving to leave this closed.

Staff used to be able to do this for images uploaded to Imgur, I'm going to assume they can still do this for images uploaded to the new host.
Since it sounds like you have nothing to flag like the post I just linked suggests though, use the Contact option at the bottom of the page, this would probably fall under other-other and then you can include the links in your explanation and request for them to be taken down.
